# Duplicate column name oracle 12c

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What is the problem? It says duplicate column name. I am allowed to have columns with the same name in different tables and access them using the table names and the . operator. I am using Oracle Database 12c.

```
CREATE VIEW R1
AS SELECT *
FROM Table1 v, Table2 p
where v.V#=p.V#;
```

Comment: You can have columns with the same name in different tables , but what if they both are to exist with the same name in the created view?

Comment: create view r1 (c1, c2, c3 ...) as select ...

Comment: also, you need to go and find out about ANSI-92 standard join syntax. Comma separated tables in a `FROM` clause is so 1990.

Comment: @ninesided what are the newer ways? I am a student testing stuff out and I have no idea whether there are some new ways of doing these things.

Comment: @ThePraetor google for ANSI-92 standard join syntax!

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly list which columns you are selecting. If you use `SELECT * FROM ...` to create the view then the columns will be set when the view is first defined and will not change - i.e. if you alter one of the underlying tables to add a column it will not be added to the view until you recompile the view.

Don't select both columns of an `INNER JOIN` - its unnecessary and you will just transfer the same data to the user twice.

Provide aliases for any duplicate column names.

```
CREATE VIEW R1 AS
SELECT v.COL1,
       v.COL2,
       v.COL3,
       -- Dont need to include p.COL1 as we've got v.COL1 already and they are equal.
       p.COL2 AS ALTERNATE_COL2,
       p.COL3 AS ALTERNATE_COL3
FROM   TABLE1 v
       INNER JOIN
       TABLE2 p
       ON ( v.COL1 = p.COL1 )
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW R1 ( COL1, COL2, COL3, ALTERNATE_COL2, ALTERNATE_COL3 ) AS
SELECT v.COL1,
       v.COL2,
       v.COL3,
       -- Dont need to include p.COL1 as we've got v.COL1 already and they are equal.
       p.COL2,
       p.COL3
FROM   TABLE1 v
       INNER JOIN
       TABLE2 p
       ON ( v.COL1 = p.COL1 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everyone <3. Though I want to add a comment that, from a student's perspective, the new syntax sucks. They are just trying to be "cute", but this is in no way practically functional. Maybe I want to do 15 joins. Instead of writing everything with a "=" sign I will have to bother with these stupid details. Maybe I'm wrong and there is an easier way, I am just learning. Best wishes guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will show you the list of columns that are defined in both tables.

```
 select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE1'
 intersect
 select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE2'
```

You can not use select * but must explicitely list the required columns.
For those columns that are in both tables you must qualify with the alias e.g.
p.column1

If you need both of them you must rename the columns e.g.

```
p.column1 as P_COLUMN1, v.column1 as V_COLUMN1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everyone <3.

Though I want to add a comment that, from a student's perspective, the new syntax sucks. They are just trying to be "cute", but this is in no way practically functional. Maybe I want to do 15 joins. Instead of writing everything with a "=" sign I will have to bother with these stupid details.
 Maybe I'm wrong and there is an easier way, I am just learning. Best wishes guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly type out the column names using table alias

```
CREATE VIEW R1
AS SELECT v.col1,v.col2,...p.col3,...
FROM Table1 v, Table2 p
where v.V#=p.V#;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kalyan Chavali commented, you have at least one pair of columns with the same name in the two tables.

Either specify a column name list:

```
CREATE VIEW R1 (c1, c2, c3...)
AS SELECT *
FROM Table1 v
  JOIN Table2 p ON v.V# = p.V#;
```

Or use column aliases:

```
CREATE VIEW R1
AS SELECT v.c1 as c1, v.c2 as c2, ... p.c1 as cx, p.c2 as cy ...
FROM Table1 v
  JOIN Table2 p ON v.V# = p.V#;
```

Note the modern explicit JOIN syntax!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everyone <3. Though I want to add a comment that, from a student's perspective, the new syntax sucks. They are just trying to be "cute", but this is in no way practically functional. Maybe I want to do 15 joins. Instead of writing everything with a "=" sign I will have to bother with these stupid details. Maybe I'm wrong and there is an easier way, I am just learning. Best wishes guys :)

Comment: New explicit JOIN syntax is easier to read and write (after some practicing). And they are much easier to convert to OUTER JOIN if needed, that only is reason enough!